# How to style a JSON block in Github Wiki?

Tags: json, github, markdown, wiki

Is there a way to nicely format/style `JSON` code in `Github Wiki` (i.e Markdown preferred)?

Something like this with few colors (or bold) and correct indentation:

http://www.freeformatter.com/json-formatter.html#ad-output

Comment: Just paste already-prettified JSON into a code block.

Comment: @MattBall But that doesn't work?

Answer (score 608, accepted):

Some color-syntaxing enrichment can be applied with the following blockcode syntax

````
```json
Here goes your json object definition
```
````

**Note:** This won't prettify the json representation. To do so, one can previously rely on an external service such as **[jsbeautifier.org](http://jsbeautifier.org/)** and paste the prettified result in the wiki.

Answer (score 151):

````
```javascript
{ "some": "json" }
```
````

I tried using `json` but didn't like the way it looked. `javascript` looks a bit more pleasing to my eye.

Comment: +1 - I like it so I can put `//` comments in the block for a little description.  Since it's not valid JSON, the json block makes it ugly

Comment: Thanks for the hint, for some reason GitHub was making a simple JSON array unnecessarily ugly, now it's just fine :)

Answer (score 49):

### ***2019 Github Solution***

````
```yaml
{
   "this-json": "looks awesome..."
}
````

#### Result

[image]

If you want to have keys a different colour to the values, set your language as `yaml`

[@Ankanna's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46811028/2217801) gave me the idea of going through [github's supported language list](http://www.rubycoloredglasses.com/2013/04/languages-supported-by-github-flavored-markdown/) and `yaml` was my best find. (No other language had keys a different colour to values on github).

Also you can use comments in `yaml` with `//`

Comment: Still the same method in 2023

Comment: For my resolve, I must add a closing ``` with the same indentation, otherwise there are issues with writing another code-block.

Comment: Yeah, we do need the closing ``` on github, but unfortunately here on SO, there is no way to display those in this answer without wrecking the formatting for the rest of the answer

Answer (score 14):

I encountered the same problem. So, I tried representing the `JSON` in different Language syntax formats.But all time favorites are `Perl`, `js`, `python`, & `elixir`.

This is how it looks.

The following screenshots are from the `Gitlab` in a markdown file. 
This may vary based on the colors using for syntax in `MARKDOWN` files.

[image: JsonasPerl]

[image: JsonasPython]

[image: JsonasJs]

[image: JsonasElixir]