# How to highlight JSON block in Gitlab Wiki (Markdown)?

Tags: gitlab, markdown

I want to highlight & color the syntax for json data in GitLab Markdown.

**Input Json**

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "first_name": "Jeanette",
    "last_name": "Penddreth",
    "gender": "Female"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "first_name": "Giavani",
    "last_name": "Frediani",
    "gender": "Male"
  }
]
```

**Expected Output**

[image: a]

When I was copy paste the beautified json data in wiki it seems to be like paragraph, which leads to less readability .

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Method1**

Place three semicolons on the start and end of json data like below.

```
;;;

json data here

;;;
```

NB: When we are placing any text before leading three semicolons this method won't work.

[Reference](https://gitlab.com/help/user/markdown#front-matter)

**Method2**

````
```json

json data here

```
````

Comment: Just additional info, for other languages it works as well: 
```

```yaml 

```
or 

```

```php 

```

Comment: the backticks work on github whereas semicolons dont

Comment: The first method seems to be GitHub specific but the second one works with other wiki services

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to [How to style JSON block in Github Wiki?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14901245/how-to-style-json-block-in-github-wiki)

Use a code fence:

````
```json

your JSON here

```
````

See https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/markdown.html#colored-code-and-syntax-highlighting

This will add color highlighting but won't beautify the code (change whitespace) -- you have to do that yourself which you can do with `jq` on the command line or using an external service such as https://beautifier.io/

Comment: Yes. You are correct. For beautify we need to use some beautifier. Seems that I have inputted non beautified json. That's an issue with the question I asked. I will edit it.

Answer (score 0):

[GitLab 15.0 (May 2022)](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/05/22/gitlab-15-0-released/#edit-code-blocks-links-and-media-inline-in-the-wysiwyg-editor) does include syntax highlighting

> GitLab 15.0 includes a few exciting improvements to speed up your workflow in the WYSIWYG Markdown editor for your wikis.
>
> You’ll find no more un-styled, monochrome code blocks: choose from over 100 languages in the dropdown list above the code block so your CSS, YAML, and Python code are distinct from each other with accurate syntax highlighting.
>
> The code blocks will even inherit your preferred syntax highlighting theme.
>
> You can also quickly copy the code block to your clipboard for use in your code editor of choice.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/15_0/inline-editing-in-wysiwyg.png]